# Trigonometric integrals in the complex numbers

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, trigonometry

What's the procedure for solving trigonometric integrals such as

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{2+\cos\theta} \text{ ?}$$

---

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_.28IIIa.29_trigonometric_integrals.2C_the_general_procedure

gives an example of $$\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{1+\sin^2(t)}$$

but doesn't explain how this integral is equivalent to

$$\frac{1}{4}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{4iz}{z^4-6z^2+1} \, dz$$

Comment: Set $z=e^{i\theta}$, so $\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}(z+z^{-1})$.

Comment: It is explaeind:''....use the substituion $z=e^{ix}$....''. read carefully!

Answer (score 2):

*Solution*

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2 + \cos x}\ \text{d}x$$

Let's step into complex plane.

We use the substitution $\cos x = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}(z + z^{-1})$; $\text{d}x = \text{d}z/iz$ then we get

$$f(z) = -\frac{i}{z\left(2 + \frac{1}{2}z + \frac{1}{2z}\right)}$$

We find singularities:

$$z_1 = -2+\sqrt{3} ~~~~~~~~~~~ z_2 = -2-\sqrt{3}$$

The singularity $z_1$ is in our region and we will add the following residue

$$\text{Res}(-2-\sqrt{3}, f(z)) = -\frac{1}{3}i \sqrt{3}$$

the other singularity will be skipped because it's not in our region.
Thence the sum is

$$2\pi i \sum \text{Res}(z, f(z)) = \frac{2}{3}\pi\sqrt{3}$$

Which is the solution of the integral.

Comment: Define singularities and your use of residuals

Comment: @mavavilj Singularities are the solution of $\text{Denominator} = 0$, and since it's a second degree equation, they are easy to find.

The use of residue, well I can say the the first singularity is ok because it's inside the unit circle. The second one is out, so we neglect it. 

For a better comprehension you should *study* the theory, and not go by examples only!